# QGIS 2.99.0 Providers not available in processing options

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler, qgis-3

I just wanted to have a deeper look at the graphical modeller in QGIS 2.99.0-147, and I stumbled upon the providers not available under Settings|Options...|Processing|Providers as shown in the screenshot below (Good idea to move it away from the processing menu by the way...).

[image]

I installed it with the 64bit OSGeo4W installer on Windows 10, and it is installed as QGIS *2.99.0 with GRASS 7.2.1 (Nightly)*, so shouldn't at least provider 'GRASS' be available?

[image]

And where have all the others gone (e.g. SAGA)? Will they be there again in QGIS 3.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3.0 is still a work in progress - not all providers are available yet.